# Help ID maker of huge film cap, 50mm x 35mm x 24mm -- AD 256K 250V MP

Tags: capacitor, identification

I just pulled this thing from a large board, I think it's part of an inverter.
The board also has a huge CM choke, 8 IRF260N and other fets.  No manufacter shown.  This thing was part of the input filter it looks like, there are two screw terminals for the input.

Here is a picture.  The "256 250V MP" plus the makers logo are the only markings.  Size is 50 x 35 x 24 mm.

I've spent more than 30 mins doing the Google thing, looking at more than 10 pages of various logos.  Did I somehow miss it, or was it a rare company?
Who made this??

Ok, I know it's a 25uF 250V metalized paper capacitor, I would like to find out who made it.  I have seen none this big with this small a value.

[![US penny for scale[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lW98k.jpg): https://i.stack.imgur.com/2NZFF.jpg
[image: US penny for scale of lettering]

Comment: Unobtainium supplier or specs , look for similar https://spectrum.ieee.org/computing/embedded-systems/when-life-gives-you-no-mlccs-make-use-of-polymer-capacitors

Comment: It's a Chinese manufacturer, unless you know chinese, you won't find information on the company. The company might not even exist anymore.

Comment: So, you recognize the logo, but the companies name does not transliterate??  I just find that weird because every other part on that board out side of surface mount caps, resistors and the ferrite beads on the FET's legs are a brand names I recognize..

Comment: Dearborn makes film caps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found the real manufacturer of this cap, or at least the logo matches 100%.
It is [AID Electronics Corporation](http://www.aid.com.tw/aboutus.htm) out of Taiwan.
As you can see, they use it in the same fashion and design.

[image: AID MP Caps]

I was looking for information on a different film capacitor, and the logo caught my eye.
They are NOT a paper film cap.

Answer (score 1):

Who makes it? Most likely a company called XN QJALYCY

Here is a cap with an AD marking on it also, they say the brand name is XN QJALYCY, which won't help you much unless you know what the chinese equivalent for it is.

[image]
Source: https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32380263065.html

Comment: That answers my question.  Thank you.  I was hoping to find out what kind of specs it has.  Time to dig out the old LCR meter...

Comment: good find on Logo. You should expect Film Caps are closest to ideal specs.  Japanese Tier1: TW/German Tier 2 , Chinese Tier 3 for purity of plastic from contaminants that promote/accelerate breakdown aging rate

Comment: Chinese manufacturers make it really hard to find information, they are only interested in selling a product, they could care less about the customer.

Comment: Unless they are importing them from Taiwan, I would call it a fake.  The AID website, that I linked in my answer, uses the logo EVERYWHERE...